# Sum of symmetric random variables inequality $P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max}\sum_{k=1}^i Y_k >a)\le2P(\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k>a)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X_n=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$ where $Y_k$ are independent symmetric random variables. Symmetric mean that $P(Y_k\in B)=P(-Y_k\in B)$ for all Borel sets $B.$
>
> I would like to prove that that for any real $a,$
>
> $$P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max}X_i>a)\le2P(X_n>a).$$

Denote $A_i=\{X_1\le a,\ldots,X_{i-1}\le a,X_i>a\}$ and $B=\{X_n>a\}.$

I can write $P(B)=\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i\cap B).$

Now $$P(A_i\cap B)\ge P(A_i\cap \{X_n\ge X_i\})=P(A_i)P(X_n\ge X_i)$$

The event $\{X_n\ge X_i\}$ is $\{Y_{i+1}+\ldots+Y_n\ge 0\}$.

If I can prove that $P(\{Y_{i+1}+\ldots+Y_n\ge 0\})\ge1/2$ then I am done. But not sure how can I prove that. I am sure that I need the symmetric hypothesis because I still have not used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Z$ is a symmetric random variable, then $\mathbb P\left(\left\{  Z\geqslant 0 \right\} \right) \geqslant 1/2$. This is due to the fact that 
$$2\mathbb P\left(\left\{  Z\geqslant 0 \right\} \right)=\mathbb P\left(\left\{  Z\geqslant 0 \right\} \right)+\mathbb P\left(\left\{  Z\leqslant 0 \right\} \right)=1+\mathbb P\left(\left\{  Z= 0 \right\} \right).$$
Now, the justification that $Z:=\sum_{j=i+1}^nY_j$ is symmetric rests on the fact that by independence and symmetry, the vectors $\left(Y_j\right)_{j=i+1}^n$ and $\left(-Y_j\right)_{j=i+1}^n $ have the same distribution. If two vectors (say of dimension $N$) $V$ and $V'$ share the same distribution then for any Borel-measurable function $f \colon\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb R$, the random variables $f\left(V\right)$ and $f\left(V'\right)$ have the same distribution. Use this with $f(x_1,\dots,x_N)=x_1+\dots+x_N$.

Comment: thanks but I still don't understand why $Z$ is symmetric, Ok for $(Y_j)_{j=i+1}^n$ we have (by independence) $P_{(Y_{j+1},\ldots,Y_{n})}=P_{Y_{j+1}}\times \ldots\times P_{Y_n}=P_{-Y_{j+1}}\times \ldots\times P_{-Y_n}=P_{(-Y_{j+1},\ldots,-Y_{n})}$. Not sure how can I use $Z.$

Comment: @Alex I have added more details.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this property or I forgot it lol. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is awesome but rather high-level. I will give a more direct proof here.

First,

**Proposition 1.** If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables symmetric about 0, then $X+Y$ is also symmetric about 0.

One can easily generalize the above to the sum of finitely many such random variables. Now, assume this proposition is true, we can conclude that $Y=Y_{i+1}+\dotsm+Y_n$ is also symmetric, hence

$$P(Y\geq 0) = P(Y>0)+P(Y=0)\geq P(Y>0)+\frac{1}{2}P(Y=0) = \frac{1}{2}$$

with the last equality due to $Y$ symmetric. Hence, all we need to show is proposition 1.

*Proof of Proposition 1*. We first recall the following basic theorem about convolution (which is Eqn (20.34) in Billingsley Probability and Measure):

**Theorem 1.** Let $X, Y$ be independent, then for any Borel set $H$,

$$P(X+Y\in H)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(Y\in H-x)\mu(dx)$$

Using this theorem and denote the distribution of $X$ with $\mu$, we can directly write

\begin{align}
P(X+Y\in -H)
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(Y\in -H-x)\mu(dx) & \text{(by Theorem 1)} \\\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(Y\in H+x)\mu(dx) & \text{(since $Y$ symmetric)} \\\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \mu(dx) & \text{(let $g(x)=P(Y\in H+x)$)} \\\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(-x) \mu(dx) & \text{($X$ is symmetric, see more below)}  \\\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(Y\in H-x)\mu(dx) \\\\
&= P(X+Y\in H). &\text{(by Theorem 1, again)}
\end{align}

One step uses the fact that, if $\mu$ is symmetric, then for any measurable and integrable $f$, $\int f(x)\mu(dx)=\int f(-x)\mu(dx)$. One can see this by considering first an indicator function (and then generalizes to simples functions, and then general functions). $\square$